# How to use Guavas Splitter and retain delimiters (without regex)?

Tags: java, split, guava

Is there a simple way of using Guavas Splitter to split a string and retain the delimiters without using regex?

Something like

```
String string = "1+2-3*40";
Splitter splitter = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.DIGIT.negate()).retainDelimiters();
```

That gives

```
[1, +, 2, -, 3, *, 40]
```

I know about Splitter.onpattern() but that would require I give it a regular expression (yet thats what am trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done in Guava now but you may [submit a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/list). BTW what would be the output for `"1+3**2"`? I think pattern would be unambiguous here.